# Python serialize HTTPFlow object (MITM)

Tags: python, serialization, ipc, mitmproxy

I am using [mitmproxy](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/introduction.html), a python man-in-the-middle (MITM) proxy for HTTP, to modify on the fly the HTTP request of a certain website.

**Goal:**

For test purposes, when it receives an HTTP request, it should save it (it receives a [HTTPFlow](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/dev/models.html#mitmproxy.models.HTTPFlow) object) and the next time the same request will be made i need to resent the exact same *data/html/header/resourses/ecc..* to the browser.

**Problem:**

The obvious solution is to serialize the object but **it isn't serializable**!

I cannot simply **keep it in memory** because i need to restart the proxy during the tests

What can i do to achieve my goal?

**Details:**

I have already tried *pickle*, *cPickle* and *marshal* with the following errors:

> - a class that defines __slots__ without defining __getstate__ cannot be pickled
> - can't pickle CDataGCP objects
> - ValueError: unmarshallable object

**Ideas**:

- 1) how much is it a bad idea to change the original object **to make it serializable**? and how can i do it?
- 2) what if the main process **communicate with a second always-alive python process** which simply keep the object in memory? 
  are they still need to comunicate obj serializing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution (the HTTPFlow obj has a method to get the state)

Imports

```
from mitmproxy.models import HTTPFlow
from mitmproxy.models import HTTPResponse
```

Save state:

```
cached_state = http_flow_response.response.get_state()
```

Load state:

```
# create the obj 
http_response = HTTPResponse(
        cached_state['http_version'], # "HTTP/1.1"
        cached_state['status_code'],  # 200
        cached_state['reason'],       # "Ok"
        cached_state['headers'],      # Headers(content_type="...")
        cached_state['content'])      # str
# send the obj
http_flow_request.reply(cached_http_response)
```